# Very hard to engage reverse gear when engine running

Tags: clutch, manual-transmission, hyundai, gears, elantra

Hyundai elantra 2009, recently its really hard to engage reverse when engine running (grinding noise). When driving its also easier to change speed when rpms is matched.

I already changed clutch Master AND Release cylinders. Everything bleeded properly and also adjusted clutch pedal free play.

I dont understand, its really easy to change speed when engine is NOT running

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Yeah, that's a clutch issue. At risk of stating the obvious, you know that the *clutch proper* is a wear item/consumable, like a brake pad, right?

Comment: Yes sure, but I though that a clutch wear was causing slipping not hard to change gears